# User assigned roles using discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to program a bot using discord.py for a discord server. I want to make a command that would allow users to assign themselves name colors (i.e Red or Blue) I tried to achieve this by creating roles. But I am having some trouble assigning roles using the newest form of discord.py.

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, * role: discord.Role):
  user = ctx.message.author
  await user.add_roles(role)
```

Does anyone know how to fix the error I'm getting. The error is given below:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: it seems like the code snippet you posted has nothing to do with the error. Can you post your whole code and the complete traceback?

Comment: This is a typo, you're missing a comma after the star in the parameter list: `async def role(ctx, *, role: discord.Role):`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the issue is the '*'...

If you use your code and add a print line to see what is actually passed to your method you will see this result:

> Code

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, * role: discord.Role):
  print(role)
  user = ctx.message.author
  await user.add_roles(role)
```

> Output

```
(<Role id=671750373761089546 name='Red'>,)
Ignoring exception in command role:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dual/PyProjects/Discord/Chandler/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 57, in role
    await user.add_roles(role)
  File "/home/dual/PyProjects/Discord/Chandler/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/member.py", line 616, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dual/PyProjects/Discord/Chandler/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/dual/PyProjects/Discord/Chandler/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/dual/PyProjects/Discord/Chandler/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'
```

If you remove the '*' and keep everything else the same this is what it looks like:

> Code

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, role: discord.Role):
  print(role)
  user = ctx.message.author
  await user.add_roles(role)
```

> Output

```
Red
```

Without the '*' the role is added to the user who called the command. This only works if the role is spelled correctly and is case sensitive so I would advise implementing some sort of input validation.

Edit:
[This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/) explains about *args and **kwargs in python. It may be useful to check it out to get a better understanding of how to pass arguments to a function :D